# Problems to install Django in Windows

Tags: pip, anaconda

Now I'm using Windows10 and Python in vscode, When I tried to install Django by `%pip install Django`, there's the following error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))) - skippingNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))) - skipping
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /simple/django/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)'))': /simple/django/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (d:\program files\anaconda\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

What should I do now?

Besides install in Python code, I've also tried to install in Anaconda, which also have some errors for installation.

Comment: Check your PC date time, is it in-sync with internet

Comment: You have two issues, one probably being a consequence of the other. So first, you seem to have network connectivity issues. And the second is that you seem to have a lot of corrupted files in _pip_'s cache (symptom is all the invalid distribution names where the first letter is replaced with a dash `-`). -- You can probably use `pip cache` to inspect and clean the cache. But first you probably need to fix your network issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of pip installed by running the following command:

‍    `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

2. Try installing Django again using pip:

`pip install Django`

3. If the above steps did not work,you can try adding the --trusted-host option
   when installing Django using pip:

`pip install Django --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`

Comment: Since OP is using anaconda, it should be `conda upgrade pip`